# Error getting data from Google Places

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get places from the Google Places API but I don't get any value. I always get the same error and I don't know why.

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl() {

    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        //Define connection
        url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json");
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        Log.d(TAG, "Conexión establecida");

        //Send data
            String parameters = "?location=38.26,-0.70";
            parameters+="&radius=5000";
            parameters+="&key=API_KEY_SERVER_APPLICATIONS";
            parameters+="&types=restaurant";


        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        wr.write(parameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Datos enviados");
        Log.d(TAG, "ResponseCode: " + String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));

        //Display what returns POST request

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String json;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            br.close();

            //System.out.println(""+sb.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "sb: " + sb.toString());


            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);

            // Parse the String to a JSON Object
            result = new JSONObject(json);

        }else{
            //System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "urlConnection.getResponseMessage(): " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            result = null;
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "UnsuppoertedEncodingException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error JSONException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return JSON Object
    return result;

}
```

The error that I get always is:

> 06-22 15:42:08.456: D/GetDataFromURL(22138): ResponseCode: 200
>
> 06-22 15:42:08.462: D/GetDataFromURL(22138):
>
> sb: {
>
> 06-22 15:42:08.462: D/GetDataFromURL(22138):    "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
>
> 06-22 15:42:08.462: D/GetDataFromURL(22138):    "html_attributions" : [],
>
> 06-22 15:42:08.462: D/GetDataFromURL(22138):    "results" : [],
>
> 06-22 15:42:08.462: D/GetDataFromURL(22138):    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
>
> }

Note: Previously, I have created an API KEY like "Key for serve applicactions", other like "Key for Android applications" and tested with both? The API Key that I use is the API Key for server applications.

Comment: I have created an API KEY for browser applications and it doesn't works!!! I've got the same error!!! I don't know what to do!!! Can anybody help me, please? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

find detailed documentation here -

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm going to prove with this new url. When I'll do it, I will tell you the result!!

Comment: Hi @Sunny Garg!!! I have update my url and it doesn't work :( I have updated my previous question. Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this in your `Androidmanifest.xml` in `application tag`

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Here is the [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) which will help you for API key.

Comment: In my AndroidManifest.xml is the API_KEY for Google Maps, but the API KEY that I need to Google Places is a Key for server applications and this key I already have previosuly.